# Check errors/warnings while installing python modules from code using pip

Tags: python-3.x, module, pip

I want to report those modules which failed to install by checking for any errors. Suppose I have a code with wrong or misspelled module-name. I want my code to print the module name for which installation failed due to some reason. For example:

```
import pip
pip.main(['install', 'someMisspelledModuleName==1.2.3'])
```

I have a dictionary from which I am reading such module names and their versions and installing it from my code itself in Python 3.4. When I am executing this script in Python Shell, it just gives red-coloured warning, which is not an error and hence I can't handle it.

Please tell me how to handle such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip.main(…)` returns a status code, one of the [predefined](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/pip/status_codes.py). Just check if it's SUCCESS or no:

```
import sys, pip
rc = pip.main(['install', 'someMisspelledModuleName==1.2.3'])
sys.exit(rc)
```

I just exit here using the result code.